# How many green-red snakes are there?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Please refer to the image an example of so-called "green-red snake" here, starting from number 10, and finally arrives 15:
[image]

Like a krait, a green-red snake has green band or red band. You can have two or more consecutive green or red bands.

Each band start with a number $a$, end with a number $c$, and has a number $b$ in the middle.

If it's a green band, then $a+b=c$; otherwise, on a red band, $a-b=c$.

Each number may only appear once on a green-red snake.

So the picture is an example of 9 bands green-red snake using up all 19 numbers from 1 to 19.
Obviously, via so we can construct a green-red snake for numbers from $1$ to $2n+1$.

Question: are there other ways to consutruct a green-red snake using up all numbers from $1$ to $19$, and how many green-red snakes are there?

More generally, how many green-red snakes are there using all numbers from $1$ to $2n+1$?

Comment: Does the row of numbers that the snake jumps between have to be a row of consecutive numbers?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis no no.. i just align the snake so as this is a smart way of construct a green-red snake, there are actually other ways

Comment: My computer says the counts for odd $n=3$ to $n=21$ are $4$, $12$, $26$, $96$, $370$, $1372$, $7554$, $48368$, $312568$, $2239448$. It's not in the OEIS, and I don't see any pattern to it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis you came out with a python program just now? that's quick! any interesting patterns on possible green-red snake, beside the one above?

Comment: I think this is an open question in discrete mathematics. When rephrased in graph theory terms, you are looking for $2k$, where $k$ is the number of $1$-super graceful labellings of the path $P_{n+1}$. From [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.01188.pdf), Theorem 2.8, each graceful path labelling induces a 1-super graceful labelling with odd vertices. However, the number of graceful labellings of a path is unknown with the best result I found present [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256693862_A_note_on_the_number_of_graceful_labellings_of_paths).

Comment: @NikoWielopolski thx for the info. it's a bit too deep for me. my most interested point is, are there other patterns to build such a snake?

Comment: From your snake you can build at least two others. You obtain the first one by changing the direction of the snake -- then each green edge turns red and each red edge turns green, and the snake is different. Less straightforwardly, you can use the mentioned Theorem 2.8 in such a case, because the labels of your edges constitute a set $\{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$. For the nodes, change each label $u$ to $2u-2n-1$ (so $2u - 19$ in this case), and for the edges change each label $e$ to $2e$. You'll get a new snake with only odd integers in the nodes and even integers on the edges

Comment: @NikoWielopolski thank you! the first one is trivial, but the 2nd is amazing!